# Drupal 7: facebook comment for article only

Tags: comments, social-network

I need Facebook comment for Drupal 7.

Which one can I use?

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fi_FI/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=409074972499544";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

If I use above code it shows me comment of any article for all article.  I need to display comment for article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use

- [**Facebook Comments Box**](https://drupal.org/project/facebook_comments_box) : This module gives your site the ability of using Facebook's Comments Box social plugin. It will create a **block** just configure only for **article**. You can check this [video](http://vimeo.com/33484356)
- [**Facebook Comments Social Plugin**](https://drupal.org/project/facebook_comments) : Implement Facebook commenting with settings on the level of both content type and node.
- Using **[Facebook plugin code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments)**

  `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="[CURRENT_ARTICLE_PAGE_URL]" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>`
  NOTE :

  - **YOUR_URL** : Updated **current URL** based on each article.

Comment: i used it but not work

Comment: I have updated my answer for **Facebook plugin code**, just need to updated your current URL in the FB plugin code.

Comment: when Using Facebook plugin code in any article, ans when comment in one article, this comment its show for all article, its wrong it must see in article who's i comment in it

Comment: Thats why you need to use **CURRENT ARTICLE PAGE URL**, so that the comments will load based on the current page URL.

Comment: ok but how can i get CURRENT ARTICLE PAGE URL

Comment: Use this code : `$path = url(current_path(), array('absolute' => TRUE));`

Comment: As mentioned, the Facebook Comments Social Plugin (a Drupal module) is probably the way to go. It's not terribly difficult to setup and it integrates Facebook's Comments API/tool. Tutorial: http://www.daymuse.com/blogs/drupal-facebook-comments-social-plugin-module-tutorial